# how to read file from resource folder in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to read an xml file from resource folder which is **inside** **WebContent** in the eclipse project. The problem is that i'm unable to read the file from resources folder but its working fine by giving a path outside(ie,E:/new/test.xml).

```
File file = new File(request.getSession().getServletContext().getContextPath()+"/resources/new/test.xml");
```

Can anyone please help me to solve the issue..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can read content from the classpath as follows :

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/new/test.xml");
```

In eclipse Webcontent is not in the classpath, by default the only thing in the classpath is /src/test to see what's in your classpath go to the project-settings -> Java Build Path, then add folders on the source tab, all the folders will then be in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getClass().getResource("new/test.xml");
```

or you can directly use file object

```
File file=new File("new/test.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with spring, so use spring capabilities:

```
@Value("classpath:new/test.xml")
private Resource resource;

public void doSomeThing(){

    File file = resource.getFile();

    [...]
}
```

[image]